# Select Rows with matching columns from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am fairly certain that this is something simple, but every example I have tried is failing.  I want to query a table like this

```
ID   Part_Type   Station_Type
---  ---------   ------------
1    5           234
2    5           846
3    5           234
4    6           585
5    6           585
6    7           465
```

and return the rows  1 and 3, as well as 4 and 5.
That is, I want to return rows where two of their columns match.
It is similar to this question: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122794/select-based-on-matching-columns) but needs to be done on one table only.  That query will find a match for every row, but I only want rows that have matching values in two columns.  How do I go about find that?

Thank you

Comment: What should happen if three rows all have the same Part_Type and Station_Type?

Comment: It should return all three.  Basically I am looking to return "groups" of rows that each have matching columns.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select t1.id, t1.part_type, t1.station_type
from yourtable t1
where exists (select part_type, station_type
              from yourtable t2
              where t1.part_type = t2.part_type
                and t1.station_type = t2.station_type
              group by part_type, station_type
              having count(id) > 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48af7/5)

Comment: Depending on the requirements I'd suggest substituting `having count(id) = 2` with `having count(id) > 1` Something along these lines: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48af7/6

Answer (score 4):

```
select id, part_type, station_type 
from myTable t1
where exists (select 1 from myTable t2
              where t1.part_type = t2.part_type
                  and t1.station_type = t2.station_type
                  and t1.id <> t2.id)
```

Comment: Both yours an bluefeet's answer works and the only reason I am accepting his is for the "group by" he put in.  It makes the information a little easier to read.

Comment: This answer is shorter and much more understandable to me than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think a [self-join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms177490%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM table t1 
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.Part_Type = t2.Part_Type 
  AND t1.Station_Type = t2.Station_Type
  AND t1.Id <> t2.Id
```

Comment: you need something to avoid duplicates. As written every row will always match itself.

Comment: Oops, you're right, didn't think through. Updated my answer and upvoted yours.