# How to get a data if where conditions are all data

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the following table structure:

```
Column1     Column2   Column3
Value1.1    Value2.1   data1
Value1.2    Value2.2   data2
```

I want use my `column1` data as a filter condition column.
How can I write a t-sql query with the following filter conditions :

```
where Value1.1 = Value2.1
```

will bring me `data1`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example.  Are you looking for Column1 to equal Column2 or for Column to equal a value regardless if it exist in column2?

Comment: Do you want to compare the last two characters on Column1 and Column2?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand the question. But maybe the following website will be able to shed some light on the WHERE clause: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp There is even a `Try it yourself` button where you can experiment a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select Rows with matching columns from SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101457/select-rows-with-matching-columns-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. Is this what you are asking for ?

```
select Column3
from the_table
where col1 = col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Column3 FROM YourTable WHERE Column1 = Value2.1
```

or you can replace the Value2.1 with your column name if you want to retrieve the filter result which Column1 has the same value with Column2 like this:

```
SELECT Column3 FROM YourTable WHERE Column1 = Column2
```