# Anti MultiAccount [MySQL]

Tags: mysql

I'm creating Anti MultiAccount in MySQL.I have big problems with MultiAccounts in my game so I need strong security.
Now I'm make that every connection in my game log in mysql.With information about ip and time login.
Every time when player connect on my server I use this.

```
INSERT INTO MULTI(IP, Name,Country,date) VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 'Test' , 'Croatia' ,UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

Now I don't know how that Admins can see possible multiaccounts so I need:

1) How to get all user IP from MULTI table but without repetition same IP's

2) How to get all connected players but without repetition

For example:

> A player is login with IP adress 127.0.0.1
>
> B player is also login with 127.0.0.1 IP adress

So A and B player are conncted!They are possible multiaccounts,how to get them(But without repetition of course)

(Sorry for English)

Comment: As you're probably aware, IP addresses change, and can be easily changed. Detection through IP address isn't a great way to handle the isntance of multi's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select Rows with matching columns from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101457/select-rows-with-matching-columns-from-sql-server)

Comment: Yes I know.But I have protection for VPN.But with this I can detect users which enter on more accounts from same IP(There are a lot of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly do you want to select, but here is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91208b/1

```
SELECT DISTINCT multi.*  FROM multi
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT ip
  FROM multi 
  GROUP BY ip
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name)>1
  ) filter
ON multi.ip = filter.ip
```